# Erlang - Get record with highest value and record with lowest value

Tags: erlang

I want to display a price-range of a list of product-records.

Let's say I have this list of products with a binary value for amount / price.

```
Products = [#product{amount=<<"20.21">>}, #product{amount=<<"30.21">>}, #product{amount=<<"9.21">>}]
```

My goal is to display the range of prices from the min-max, e.g. <<"9.21">> - <<"30.21">>

How could one go on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).
-record(product, {name, price}).

products() ->
    [
        #product{name='a', price= <<"20.21">>}, 
        #product{name='b', price= <<"30.21">>}, 
        #product{name='c', price= <<"9.21">>},
        #product{name='d', price= <<"11.21">>}
    ].

price_range(Products) ->

    PriceFunc = fun(Product, {Min, Max}) ->
                    Price = binary_to_float(Product#product.price),
                    NewMin = min(Min, Price),
                    NewMax = max(Max, Price),
                    {NewMin, NewMax}
                end,

    InitPrice = binary_to_float(
                  (hd(Products))#product.price
                ),

    lists:foldl(PriceFunc, {InitPrice, InitPrice}, Products).
```

In the shell:

```
9> c(my).                   
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

10> Products = my:products().
[{product,a,<<"20.21">>},
 {product,b,<<"30.21">>},
 {product,c,<<"9.21">>},
 {product,d,<<"11.21">>}]

11> my:price_range(Products).
{9.21,30.21}
```

Comment: will fail in case of empty products list